# Basic doubt about cosets

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Studying some basic group theory I had the following doubt: For $H$ subgroup of a finite group $G$ (doesn't matter invariance of $H$), is it true that $$|G/H|=|\{aHa^{-1}:a \in G\}| \space (\text{where G/H is the quotient of G by H})?$$

I've tried to define the most natural function between these two sets that comes to my mind, $$f:G/H \to \{aHa^{-1}:a \in G\}$$$$aH \to aHa^{-1}$$

but I couldn't show that $f$ is well defined and that it is injective. I would appreciate if someone could tell me whether these two sets have the same number of elements or not.

Comment: What is $P$?  Did you mean $H$?

Comment: $P=H$? Also  when $H$ is normal, $|G/H|=[G:H]$ and $|G/H|=|G|/|H|$ for the finite case. Can you see why your statement is not true ?

Comment: What examples did you look at? What about $H=\{e\}$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not true. In fact, if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then (by the definition of normal) we have that for any $a\in G$, 
$$aHa^{-1}=H$$
so that
$$\{aHa^{-1}:a\in G\}=\{H\}$$
has exactly one element, whereas there is more than one element of $G/H$ as long as $G\neq H$.